# Android MediaPlayer Won't Stream from HTTP

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer2.x, android-httptransport

When setting a MediaPlayer DataSource to a HTTP URL as opposed to an HTTPS URL, no audio streams and MediaPlayer error code -38 is displayed in logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I attempted to connect to the stream using ExoPlayer instead, and received [this error](https://exoplayer.dev/troubleshooting.html#fixing-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted-errors).  Following the docs suggestion, I added the following line of code to the application tag of my application's manifest file:

```
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

I am now able to connect to the stream at HTTP URL using both ExoPlayer and MEdiaPlayer.